# ruby on rails select collection, filter results from array [enumerable]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, arraycollection

current i am trying to restrict the information feed into an option select field to only display the criteria i have selected. with the code below this seems to be working

```
         = select("schedule", :selected_players, User.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id]) { |p| [full_name(p), p.id] }, {:include_blank => 'None', :prompt => 'Add Players to Lineup'}, :multiple => "multiple")
```

the issue is that this code is display an array field type i.e `#<User:0xa559830>`

how do i get it to display the actual users name?

Answer (score 1):

Define `.to_s` method in model

Like here
https://github.com/roolo/mwstt/blob/master/app/models/project.rb#L7

Also all the mapping and searching logic should be placed in model as method which you'll just call in view, or prepare it in controller!

Comment: this code hasnt helped at all with the problem we are having :S

Comment: With informations you gave us i don't think anybody will give you another advise. Look at the application i've linked i use there foreign key select on few places

Comment: Was the link at least helpful?